# Cypress Component Testing in Gatsby

Tags: cypress, gatsby

My question is simply, can Cypress Component testing work in a Gatsby application?

I hit the setup button in the Cypress Component testing UI, and the first thing it did was failed to find my webpack config file, which I assume is because Gatsby handles this itself. So I googled "cypress component testing Gatsby" but all I get are a bunch of things about e2e Cypress testing in Gatsby, which is not helpful at all for my question.

Sometimes Google just can't help you, so I'm hoping for an answer from humans. Can this work? What is required?

Comment: Seems like a pretty broad question...

Answer (score 4):

### Of course you can

[gatsbyjs/docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/)

> Gatsby is a **React-based** open source framework for creating websites ... *yadah yadah*

If you want to test Gatsby components, you just test with [React Component Testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/react/overview).

### Of course you can't

If you want to test gatsby build artifacts  (*what would they even be* - performance? build size? security?),
you would obviously use **e2e**.

Otherwise, you could try to add gatsby to the `mount()` function (good luck with that), or hook tests into `webpack` (even sillier).

Comment: Interesting answer, makes sense. However, how specifically would I set up the cypress config for this to work, since there is no webpack config file in my Gatsby application?